# How to find out which version of Google AdMob is used in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

Google AdMob released the following statement latelty:

> Starting January 23, 2018, we will no longer support Google Mobile Ads (GMA) SDK versions lower than 7.0.0 for Android or iOS.

How can I check in unity which version of Admob SDK I am using?

Answer (score 7):

I know it's a bit old, but for anyone still looking:

1. Open AdRequest.cs (in GoogleMobileAds Api)
2. Look for the Version field parameter (IE public const string Version = "3.18.0")

Answer (score 3):

I found something like that 
project/projectName/Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml

In my project it look like this

```
<androidPackage spec="com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.2">
```

Here is the last version of sdk
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/sdk
That's why I think that's it.